Next.js Error: NEXT_REDIRECT when Redirecting to Payment Gateway URL
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to implement a payment option within my Next.js application. Upon submitting the payment, the user should be redirected to the payment gateway URL to proceed with the payment. However, I'm facing the following error when trying to use redirection from next/navigation:
Error: NEXT_REDIRECT
    at getRedirectError (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect.js:49:19)
    at redirect (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect.js:60:11)
    at $$ACTION_0 (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./api/postTopup.js:45:66)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:406
    at async t2 (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:6412)
    at async rS (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:41:1369)
    at async doRender (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1378:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1539:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1447:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1844:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1882:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:895:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:269:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:791:17)
    at async C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:331:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:151:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:328:24)
    at async invokeRender (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:174:21)
    at async handleRequest (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:353:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:377:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (C:\Users\Vishaal\Desktop\mntank\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:140:13) {
  digest: 'NEXT_REDIRECT;push;https://commerce.coinbase.com/pay/cdd442d2-7025-4765-b701-00c6bf03a98d;303;',
  mutableCookies: p {
    _parsed: Map(3) {
      'next-auth.callback-url' => [Object],
      'next-auth.csrf-token' => [Object],
      'next-auth.session-token' => [Object]
    },
    _headers: HeadersList {
      cookies: [Array],
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    }
  }
}

Here's the relevant code snippet:
export const postTopup = async (amount) => {
  const session = await getServerSession();
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: session.user.email });

  try {
    const chargeData = {
      name: "Buy Tokens",
      description: "Buying Topup Tokens",
      pricing_type: "fixed_price",
      local_price: {
        amount: amount,
        currency: "USD",
      },
      metadata: {
        id: "randomstring",
        userID: user._id,
      },
    };

    const charge = await Charge.create(chargeData);

    redirect(charge.hosted_url, "push");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};


Solved with window.open(url, '_blank')
